# Avoiding Zsh Redirection Prompt and Extraneous '1' Output

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, zsh

I'm an experienced Linux administrator and bash user. That said I haven't been able to figure out zsh's behavior given the below commands.

I expect the following command to output the filenames each on their own lines:

```
ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done
```

But the above then prompts for std redirection (anything other than std redirection throws errors):

```
pipe for>
```

If I try the following:

```
ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done\n2&>1
```

Then I get this error:

```
zsh: parse error near `&>'
```

However, if I yet again try

```
ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done
```

And at the prompt enter:

```
pipe for>2&>1
```

Then the command completes successfully with:

```
1
filename1
filename2
filename3 
the rest the filenames
```

Note that this command writes an empty file named '1'. Scrolling up in command history reveals a line identical to what I tried above:

```
ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done\n2&>1
```

Except this time it works.

Why does typing in the following command fail but waiting for the prompt and entering 2&>1 succeed despite both showing identical characters if you goes to see recent history.

`ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done\n2&>1`

```
ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done\n2&>1
pipe for>2&>1
```

Furthermore, why would

```
ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done
```

prompt for std file redirection anyway?

Note: My end goal is to essentially do:
ls | for filename in $@ do if (filename = foo); then cat $filename >> outfile.txt; fi

Comment: You're missing the `;` before `do` and `done`.

Comment: What's the point of piping `ls` to a loop that doesn't read anything? `$@` is the script arguments, not the output of `ls`.

Comment: The `>` here is unrelated to redirection. It's simply asking you to finish the for loop because `do` and `done` are only special at the start of a statement (e.g. after a `;`), so it thinks you haven't entered the loop body yet.

Comment: ...also, [parsing `ls` is buggy, nonportable, and otherwise the wrong way to iterate over filenames in the first place](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `for arg in *; do echo "$arg"; done`. If you want to iterate over _lines_, that's what a `while read` loop is for (in bash, more correctly written akin to `while IFS= read -r arg; do echo "Doing something with: $arg"; done`).

Comment: Same problem in any shell, not just `zsh`. And why not something like `cat *foo* > outfile.txt`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're making several mistakes here. Let's go over them, one by one.

- You need a `;` or a newline before both `do` and `done`.
- You cannot pipe to `$@`. If you're going to pipe, then you'll need to `read`. For example, this works:

  ```sh
  ls | while read filename; do 
    [[ $filename == $~foo ]] && print $filename
  done
  ```
- If you do want to use `$@`, then you'll need to use a function. For example, this works, too:

  ```sh
  () { 
    for filename in $@; do 
      [[ $filename == $~foo ]] && print $filename
    done 
  } $(ls)
  ```
- However, if you're going to use [`$(command substitution)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution) anyway, then you don't really need to use a function. The above can be rewritten like this:

  ```sh
  for filename in $(ls); do 
    [[ $filename == $~foo ]] && print $filename
  done
  ```

But none of the above is actually necessary for what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to print all filenames that match a pattern to a text file, then you can just do this:

```sh
# `-l` puts each item on a separate line.
# `*<->` matches all files that end in a number.
print -l - *<->  >  outfile.txt
```

### Bonus Tip

If the prompt `pipe for>` confuses you, try adding this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
export PS2='Please close this "%1_" statement. ^ '
```

Then you will instead see

```sh
% ls | for arg in $@ do echo ${arg} done
Please close this "for" statement. ^
```